# #1109 - Unknown table - Calling a procedure

Tags: mysql

I created a new procedure to delete some a row from a table.

```
    DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE DropCourse ( IN Course_Id VARCHAR(10), IN Student_Id VARCHAR(10))
BEGIN
    IF Class_Id = FALL2016.CourseId AND Student_Id = FALL2016.StudentId THEN
        delete from FALL2016
        where StudentId = Student_Id AND CourseId = Course_Id
        limit 1
        SELECT 'Course Deleted from Registry.'
    ELSE
    SELECT 'Not registered for course selected, no action taken.'
    END IF;
END;
//
DELIMITER ;
```

---

This is the table I got called FALL2016
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UjwRf.png)

Comment: After I call the procedure 
as the following,
Call CourseDrop('280', '20');
I get the Unknown table error.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the `delete` and then count the number of rows that are affected:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE DropCourse ( IN Course_Id VARCHAR(10), IN Student_Id VARCHAR(10))
BEGIN
    delete from FALL2016
    where StudentId = Student_Id AND CourseId = Course_Id
    limit 1;

    select @rc := row_count();

    IF @rc > 0 THEN
        SELECT 'Course Deleted from Registry.'
    ELSE
        SELECT 'Not registered for course selected, no action taken.'
    END IF;
END;//

DELIMITER ;
```